# are there names for functions involving the summation of vector elements?

Tags: vectors

given a vector v

v.sum -> the summation of elements

v.norm -> the normalization of V

the function is:

f(v) = v.norm * v.sum

example:

V = <1,1,3,-1>

V.sum = 4

V.norm = <0.288.., 0.288.., 0.866.., 0.288..>

f(V) = <1.15.., 1.15.., 3.46.., -1.15..>

Applying this recursively yields a set of vectors with the same normal and where the 'i'th element's magnitude is equal to the absolute value of the 'i-1'th element's sum.  It came up whilst programing and I needed to name the function (and the series).  It seems too trivial to not already have a name.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with absolute value 'i-1'th element's sum . Give an example with $f(V)$ which is written.

Comment: I don't think this has a well-known name.

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis I am a dreadful wielder of latex.  Given the above def for V and f(V), than you can say a new vector, nv = f(V).  nv 's magnitude is equal to V.sum.